# Angular momentum in movement along a straight line

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

Angular momentum is conserved when no external torque is applied, I've learned that a long time ago and know the derivation. Yet, I've now been wondering about the following case:

Let's consider a (classical) particle moving along a straight line with constant velocity $\vec{v}$, a mass $m$, and no external forces. Now, consider the angular momentum with respect to a point $O$ which is not situated along the particle's line of movement, like in the picture below.

[image]

then $\vec{r}$ is changing with time but $\vec{v}$ is not. So the angular momentum $L=\vec{r}\times \vec{v}$ will also change with time. How can this be possible, and what did I miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the property ${\bf v}\times {\bf v}={\bf 0}$ of the vector product. So if ${\bf r}\to {\bf r}+ {\bf v}t$ the angular momentum ${\bf  L} \propto {\bf r}\times {\bf v}$does not change.

Answer (score 4):

$L=\vec{r}\times \vec{v} = rv\sin\theta \times\vec{n}$

(where $r$ and $v$ are the magnitudes, $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane in which $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ lie)

$v$ is constant but $r\sin\theta$ is also constant

It's the distance between $O$ and where the dotted line crosses the $y$ axis

Answer (score 1):

We have that the angular momentum is $$\vec L = m \vec r \times \vec v$$ where $\vec r = \vec r_0 + \vec v t$ (since no external force is applied, the object simply continues with its given velocity by Newton's first Law, $\vec r_0$ is some arbitrary position, $\vec v$ the velocity, and $t$ the time).

Therefore, $$\begin{align} \vec L &= m\left( \vec r_0 + \vec v t \right)\times\vec v \\  &= m \vec r_0 \times \vec v+\vec v \times \vec vt\end{align}$$

and since $\vec v \times \vec v = 0$, we have that $$\vec L = m\vec r_0\times\vec v$$ is a conserved quantity.

Comment: $\overrightarrow{L}=\overrightarrow{r}\times m\overrightarrow{v}$

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ span an ever changing parallelogram in the $xz$ plane (referring to the image in your question). However, the *area* of that parallelogram stays fixed, because the base of the parallelogram is always $|\vec{v}|$, and the height is also always constant (equal to the distance between $O$ and the line, or the absolute value of the $z$ coordinate that defines the line). This area is constant and equal to the *magnitude* of the cross product. It is also easy to see that the *direction* of the cross product is fixed as the particle moves along the line.

So the angular momentum is in fact conserved.